# Using with = FALSE and .SD to subset ROWS of .SD

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with multiple variables which take a limited number of values. For each variable, I want to build a table counting the fraction of observations that have each value, with grouping.

Example data:

```
data = data.table(group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), 
                  Var1 =  c(1,1,2,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,3,1,2,3,1), 
                  Var2 =  c(1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,1,2,3,2,1,1,3))
```

I would like two resulting tables:

```
Var1:
group | Var1_1  | Var1_2  | Var1_3
------|---------|---------|---------
1     | .4      | .4      | .2
2     | .2      | .6      | .2
3     | .4      | .2      | .4
```

and similarly for `Var2`. This is straightforward for a single variable:

```
data[, .(Var1_1 = .SD[Var1 == 1, .N]/.N, 
         Var1_2 = .SD[Var1 == 2, .N]/.N,
         Var1_3 = .SD[Var1 == 3, .N]/.N), by = group, .SDcols = "Var1"]
```

But since I have many variables, I'd like to do this in a loop. I've played around with using `with = FALSE` both in the outer call and the `.SD` call, but haven't been able to get it right. Ideally I can pass the column name to `.SD`'s `i` subset, `.SDcols`, and, ideally, as an argument to `paste0()` to create the output variable names (e.g. `paste0(varName, "_1")`).

```
variables <- c("Var1", "Var2")
for(variable in variables) {
    data[...what should go here?...]
}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` and `prop.table` are usually handy for constructing such proportional tables.

```
lapply(variables, function(var) data[, prop.table(table(group, get(var)), margin = 1)])

#[[1]]

#group   1   2   3
#    1 0.4 0.4 0.2
#    2 0.2 0.6 0.2
#    3 0.4 0.2 0.4

#[[2]]

#group   1   2   3
#    1 0.4 0.4 0.2
#    2 0.2 0.8 0.0
#    3 0.4 0.2 0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also do this with `dcast` from `data.table`

```
lapply(variables, function(x) dcast(data[, .N , c('group', x)][, 
     Perc := N/sum(N), group][, N := NULL], group~..., value.var = "Perc", fill = 0))
#[[1]]
#   group   1   2   3
#1:     1 0.4 0.4 0.2
#2:     2 0.2 0.6 0.2
#3:     3 0.4 0.2 0.4

#[[2]]
#   group   1   2   3
#1:     1 0.4 0.4 0.2
#2:     2 0.2 0.8 0.0
#3:     3 0.4 0.2 0.4
```